# orchard cms: how to add media picker field to anew module

Tags: orchardcms, asp.net-mvc

I am building a module for orchard cms.
I would like to use the mediapiker module in my module.

Through the orchard backend interface, its possible to add a moudle to a content item.
What is not clear, is how to use one module in another.

how do I add the mediapiker field to my razor view in visual studio?

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at MediaPickerFieldDriver.cs and MediaPicker.Edit.cshtml. They are both in Orchard.Fields. That should give you everything you need.
Then again it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. If you are just trying to add a media picker field to your content type from code, then you should do it from the migration, like this:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("Product",
    builder => builder.WithField("ProductImage",
        fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder
            .OfType("MediaPickerField")
            .WithDisplayName("Product Image")));
```

Update: As @ed13 points out in his answer, for more recent versions of Orchard 1.x (1.10+), the field type is `MediaLibraryPickerField` instead of `MediaPickerField`.

Comment: There is no such method called AlterPartDefinition in Orchard 1.8. What to do in this case?

Comment: Okey found it. it comes from an extension method!

Comment: In case anyone is using a later version of Orchard, this should be of type "MediaLibraryPickerField". See full code snippet in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038109/824528

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone using a later version of Orchard (v1.10.+), the code required to add a media picker field is below:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("YourContentPart", builder =>
                builder.WithField("BackgroundImage",
                    fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder
                        .OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
                        .WithDisplayName("Background Image")));
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Can you explain how it's different from my answer?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Sure - MediaPickerField didn’t work in my version (1.10.2). I had to use MediaLibraryPickerField - assumed this was just a versioning thing. Is it not?