# orchard cms: how to add media picker field to a custom part

Tags: orchardcms

My question is simmalar to [questions/10369967/orchard-cms-how-to-add-media-picker-field-to-anew-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369967/orchard-cms-how-to-add-media-picker-field-to-anew-module)

I've created a new content part, that has a select list, a text box and ... I want to include a media picker filed.

I have added this to the content part with Bertrand Le Roy's suggestion of:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("Product",
    builder => builder.WithField("ProductImage",
        fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder
            .OfType("MediaPickerField")
            .WithDisplayName("Product Image")));
```

However I've no idea of how to show this in my custom editor View

I'm sure there should be something easy like @Display(Model.ProductImage) ... but I've followed the [writing a content part](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part) form the Orchard docs, and my model in my editor view is not dynamic.

So if such magic as @Display(Model.ProductImage) exists, how do I add the media picker item to my view model ?

**Update**

The Media picker field seems to be showing on the content types where I add this part, just not where I want it! I want to show / hide this field biased on values selected form a select list, How can I stop the default rendering of the field Content Item and Render it in my custom view ?

**Update 2**

I've added this in the model

```
 public MediaPickerField MediaPicker
        {
            get{ return (MediaPickerField)((dynamic)ContentItem).HeaderPart.Image;}

        }
```

this to the view

```
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Fields/MediaPicker.Edit", Model.MediaPicker)
```

and this is the placement.info

```
 <!-- MediaPicker -->
    <Place Fields_MediaPicker_Edit="-"/>
```

Now it looks right on the editing via cms end... but dosen't seem to save the images to the database!

Comment: Now you've moved the goalpost ;) It seems like what you are trying to do is very different from what your original question suggested. It seems like you are trying to re-use the media picker field in a very customized situation. In other words, re-use its UI but not really the field itself. The media picker extension to TinyMCE may be a better starting point for your custom part's code.

Comment: I see it as adding definition during research! ... but I see your point. I was thinking there must be a module that dose this somewhere, and couldn't think of which one. thanks I'll have a look at TinyMCE

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like `@Model.ContentItem.Product.ProductImage.Url`

Comment: using this ((dynamic)Model.ContentItem).Product.ProductImage I get Orchard.Fields.Fields.MediaPickerField, but nothing if I add the Url property, and its the shape I want to build and render.