# Orchard cms Html from IContent items

Tags: orchardcms

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073743/orchard-cms-how-to-filter-blog-post-by-taxonomy-terms#comment17761263_13073743), but instead of [changing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387698/orchard-cms-how-to-add-media-picker-field-to-a-custom-part#comment16653171_12387698) I thought it Would be better to ask a new one.

I've now got a list of IContent items using the _taxonomyService.GetContentItems(term)

as suggested by  @Bertrand Le Roy in the question mentioned above

But how do I turn this into a useful Html string, that I can update on the client via an ajax post?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IOrchardServices _services;
        private readonly IBlogService _blogService;
        private readonly IBlogPostService _blogPostService;
        private readonly IFeedManager _feedManager;
        private readonly IArchiveConstraint _archiveConstraint;
        private readonly ITaxonomyService _taxonomyService;

        public HomeController(
            IOrchardServices services, 
            IBlogService blogService, 
            IBlogPostService blogPostService,
            IFeedManager feedManager,
            IShapeFactory shapeFactory,
            IArchiveConstraint archiveConstraint,
            ITaxonomyService taxonomyService) {
            _services = services;
            _blogService = blogService;
            _blogPostService = blogPostService;
            _feedManager = feedManager;
            _archiveConstraint = archiveConstraint;
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
            Shape = shapeFactory;
            _taxonomyService = taxonomyService;
            }

        dynamic Shape { get; set; }
        public Localizer T { get; set; }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ListByArchive(string path, IEnumerable<string> category)
    {
    try
    {
        // get year and month from path
        path = path.ToLower().Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"/archive/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 9);

        var date = path.Split('/');
        var month = int.Parse(date[1]);
        var year = int.Parse(date[0]);

        // get list of terms ids from strings 
        var taxonomyPart = _taxonomyService.GetTaxonomyByName("Category");

        var terms = category.Select(cat => _taxonomyService.GetTermByName(taxonomyPart.Id, cat)).ToList();

        // get list of content items by term avoiding duplicates 
        var posts = new List<IContent>();

        foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            var items = _taxonomyService.GetContentItems(term);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (!posts.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(item.Id))
                {
                    posts.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }


        // filter by date 
        var byDate = posts.Where(x =>
                    {
                        var publishedUtc = x.ContentItem.As<CommonPart>().CreatedUtc;
                        return
                            publishedUtc != null 
                            && publishedUtc.Value.Month == month 
                            && publishedUtc.Value.Year == year;
                    });
```

....

This gets me my list of IContent, but how do I get a the html for the rendered list ?

I've tried

```
var range = byDate.Select(x => _services.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(x, "Summary"));

                var list = Shape.List();

                list.AddRange(range);


                dynamic viewModel = Shape.ViewModel().ContentItems(list);

                var html = View((object)viewModel);

 return Json(new { html = html });
```

but it returns an empty view,

```
{"html":{"MasterName":"","Model":[],"TempData":[],"View":null,"ViewBag":{},"ViewData":[],"ViewEngineCollection":[{"HostContainer":{}}],"ViewName":""}}
```

I have a view called ListByArchive.cshtml, that matches the one it the orchard.blog module.

As an aside, I should be returning a partial view result, instead of a jason result, but when I change the Action result type I get a 404. result from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is never going to work the way you think it does:

```
var html = View((object)viewModel);
```

The easiest way to return HTML representing the content item is to:

- Mark your action with *ThemedAttribute*, ie. `[Themed(false)]`
- Return `new ShapeResult(this, viewModel)` (full view) or `new ShapePartialResult(this, viewModel)` (partial view) instead of `Json(new { html = html })`

Rendering a shape/view to string inside the action is also possible, but way more tricky.

**EDIT:** I assumed you already have `/Views/ViewModel.cshtml` file in place. Like [Bertrand Le Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363821/bertrand-le-roy) noted below - if it's not there, you need to add one to be able to create a shape using `Shape.ViewModel()`.

Comment: Because you need to provide a template for all shapes you create. If you create a ViewModel shape, you need a ViewModel.cshtml template.

Comment: Also, you may want to return a partial shape result.